# Problem recording camera stream through ffmpeg - Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera, video-capture, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to record a camera stream through ffmpeg, but I'm struggling to understand how to write a correct recording command.

This is the camera format according to v4l2

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d 1 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'RG12'
    Name        : 12-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

And this is what I tried so far

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

which would return this and an empty output file

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x557fbba630] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_PARM): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x557fbba630] Time per frame unknown
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1920x1080, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
[libx264 @ 0x557fbbd6d0] MB rate (8160000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x557fbbd6d0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x557fbbd6d0] profile High 4:2:2, level 6.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x557fbbd6d0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 1000k fps, 1k tbn, 1000k tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

I'm new to ffmpeg so I can't determine which settings or properties could help me with this format, or if this format is even supported at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I am working on a Jetson board, but gstreamer or nvgstcapture are not an option

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but with output: `sudo ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i ../videos/demo-video.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 video0`

Comment: @LeoDog896 Unfortunately I haven't been working on this issue anymore so I haven't found a fix for it